# How to display posts from a different subfolder

Tags: jekyll

I am making a simple jekyll blog and I have different categories of posts which hold different articles. At some places in my blog I want to display only the articles from that specific category. I keep my categories seperated in my `_posts` folder example:

```
---_posts
   |
   |-- category1
   |-- category2
```

Inside my _posts folder I just have a folder for each category that keeps my articles. How can I display only the posts which are in catergory1 and category2, something like this:

```
    {% for post in caregory1.posts limit: 2 %}
  <div class="center-column">
<article>
  <img src="../assets/images/test-img.jpg" alt="" class="test-img">
  <p>12.12.2015</p>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum voluptates aperiam, repellendus est eius debitis
     suscipit consequatur iure et sequi ipsum eos culpa, delectus magnam amet explicabo! Voluptatem, adipisci quam.</p>

</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll derives categories from a post's *superdirectory*.
Therefore instead of having `_posts/category1`, etc, organize into **`category1/_posts`, `category2/_posts`**, etc.

Then iterate through `site.categories.category1` to render individual posts:

```
{% for post in site.categories.category1 %}
  <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
  // insert your code
{% endfor %}
```